# How to design a 2nd Order High Pass Butterworth filter with a gain of 6 dB?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, active-filter, frequency-response, high-pass-filter

I have been trying to design a 2nd order filter with a gain of 6 dB (or 2 Av), using the following Sallen-Key Topology.

[image]

I have calculated R1 and R2 to give me a desired cut-off of 1.6kHz and this part is working fine. I am however not managing to get the gain up to 6 dB.

Following the example from [this book, page 450](https://www2.mvcc.edu/users/faculty/jfiore/OpAmps/OperationalAmplifiersAndLinearICs_3E.pdf), using the Butterworth co-efficients for Second-Order Filter Parameters α = 1.414 and b = 1.0.

[image]

Calculating: R4 = 2 - α = .586 ohms

Calculating: R3 = 1 + .586/1 = 1.586 ohms

[image]

*This resistor ratio is providing a gain of 1.586 as per the Butterworth coefficients.* Thus my circuit looks like this:

[image]

The frequency response looks like this:

[image]

The above image may not be too clear, however the cut-off freq is as desired, however the gain is not 2 AV (6 dB) but 1.586 AV as per the above calculation. I would gladly provide more information if necessary.

**How can I alter the above equations to provide a gain of 2 Av while using the Butterworth coefficients?**

Comment: Should R3 and 4 calculations result in kΩ rather than Ω? It's "dB" - not "Db". 'd' for deci and 'B' for bel.

Comment: R3 and R4 calculation result is simply the ratio so units do not matter. They are in ohms since 2 - 1.414 is 0.586 Ω and not 586 Ω or 0.586 kΩ. In the circuit I provided the units are kΩ as you suggest.

Comment: They'll matter if you try to drive them with an op-amp. As long as you are aware that's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I don't understand why you are refering to page 450 of the book;

I found your circuit on page 456. Figure 11.23 "High-pass equal-component" (VCVS).

[image]

In the book they describe two types of Sallen-Key Topology filters, one is the "unit-gain"-version which as the name suggests has A<sub>v</sub>=1. and the other is the "equal-component"-version (the one you have), this one also has a specific/fixed gain associated with it which is A=3−α this is what the book sayes about the "equal-component"-version on page 449:

[image]

> "We see that the gain and damping of the filter are linked together. Indeed, for a
>   certain damping factor, only one specific gain will work properly:
>   A=3−α"

Since we know that for a butterworth-filter α must be sqrt(2) that determines our gain. So to answer the question;

> How can I alter the above equations to provide a gain of 2 Av while using the Butterworth coefficients?

**You can't without changing the basic circuit because the gain is determined by the topology and the choise of α for a butterworth-filter.**

Now to answer the broader question of

> How to design a 2nd Order High Pass Butterworth filter with a gain of 6 dB?

You can easily make the gain of your circuit almost anything you want by just adding a single resistor and fiddleing with the values of the existing like this;

**The circuit you have can be turned into this one:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2w1jb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**By replacing R2 and Rf with voltage-dividers**

Now the gain of your new circuit is going to be (3-α)(R3+R4)/R4

To make this work the following have to be true:

R3//R4=R2 <- The thevinin equivalent of R3//R4 has to be equal to the original R2

R5//R6=Rf <- The thevinin equivalent of R5//R6 has to be equal to the original Rf

R3/R4=R5/R6 <- The two voltage-dividers have to divide the output by the same amount.

Now R6 and Ri can of course be combined, but for the sake of understanding the circuit I left them seperate.

If I was you though I would go for the "unit gain"-type and then do as I have described using R3=R4 to amplify the output by 2 to get A<sub>v</sub>=2

EDIT:

I followed the example in the book for a unit-gain type, I chose 1kHz cutoff and simulated it in LT-spice with the results I got for the resistors and caps. here is a screenshot of the simulation in LT-spice showing cutoff at 1kHz, 0dB in-band gain and butterworth responce;

[image]

I then replaced the feedback resistors with voltage dividers as per my suggestion and simulated the results, below is a screenshot of the simulation in LT-spice, showing 6dB in-band gain, cutoff at 1kHz and butterworth-responce.

[image]

Sorry I know the pictures are hard to make out.

Comment: Vinzent - I dont agree with your conclusion that we "cant without changing...the circuit" realize Butterworth with a gain of two. Of course, we can (see my conntribution).

Comment: @LvW I might be wrong in that conclusion, I don't know enough of the math behind to follow your example I just based my conclusion on the comment in the book. However I know that you can make the output have any gain you want by doing as I described in the end of my answer, without changing the filter itself.

Comment: @Vinzent, in the circuit you provided above, shouldn't the capacitors be going in the positive rail of the op-amp?

Comment: (3-α)(R3+R4)/R4 does not seem to hold true on simulation since i achieved a perfect result with R£ and R4 being both equal to give in parallel 7k (14k and 14k)

Comment: @Rrz "Shouldn't the capacitors be going in the positive Rail of the op-amp?" Yes of course they should I didnt see that mistake when i drew it. Ill correct it when i get on my computer. You say that you cant get (3-a)(r3+r4)/r4 to hold true, maybe you could provide a diagram with your new component values and your measurements? That Way I can better help understand. I will also try to provide better mathematical prof/ justification why (r3+r4)/r4 is true..

Comment: sure will update calculations soon. In the meantime I have provided the unity gain circuit which has a correct cutoff. How can   (3-a)(r3+r4)/r4 = 2 while r3//r4 = 7k AND r3/r4 =r5/r6 as you suggest?

Comment: Since this is unity gain r5/r6 = 1 and so with that reasoning r3/r4 = 1 which doesn't hold true for (3-a)(r3+r4)/r4 = 2

Comment: The (3-a) part is the original gain of the equal-component-version remember, the gain of the unit-gain version is of course 1, so the equation for the gain of the unit-gain version (compensated using my method) is of course not (3-a)*(r3+r4)/r4 but rather 1(ONE)*(r3+r4)/r4 which is indeed =2 if you make r3=r4. Otherwise your calculations are correct. Basically just take the 7kohm resistor in your unit-gain circuit and replace it with a voltage divider consisting of 2*14kohm and the same with the negative-feedback resistor (the 14kohm one) and you should be good to go

Answer (score 3):

There is a straightforward solution to the problem - starting with the general transfer function of the circuit.
From this function, we can derive the following expressions for an ideal opamp...

Pole frequency: $$ \omega_p=\frac{1}{R_2C_1\sqrt{k_rk_c}} $$

Pole quality factor: $$ Q_p = \frac{\sqrt{k_rk_c}}{1+k_c+k_rk_c(1-v)} $$

Where \$ k_r = R_1/R_2 \quad k_c = C_2/C_1 \quad v = 1+\frac{R_4}{R_3} \$.

These expressions can be evaluated setting \$ v=2 \$ and \$ R_3 = R_4 \$.
One possible (simple) solution is to set \$ k_c = 1 \$ (i.e. \$ C_1 = C_2 \$).

For this condition we get: $$ Q_p = \frac{\sqrt{k_r}}{2-k_r} $$

For \$k_r\$ we have a quadratic solution:

$$ k_{r1,2} = 2 + \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+ 8 Q_p^2}}{2Q_p^2} $$

Note that only the smallest solution is valid (with the "-" sign) in order to keep \$Q_p\$ positive.

EDIT:

The transfer function for the given highpass circuit (first form) is as follows (where \$ v = 1+R_4/R_3 \$):

$$ H(s)=N(s)/D(s) $$

$$ N(s) = s^2 v R_1 R_2 C_1 C_2 $$

$$ D(s) = 1 + s[R_2(C_1+C_2)+R_1C_2(1-v)]+s^2R_1R_2C_1C_2 $$

Now we compare this circuit specific equation with the second-order general form for deriving the equations for gain, corner frequency and pole quality:

$$ H(s)=N(s)/D(s) $$

$$ N(s) = \left(\frac{s}{\omega_p}\right)^2 A_\infty $$

$$ D(s) = 1 + \frac{s}{\omega_p Q_p} + \left(\frac{s}{\omega_p}\right)^2 $$

Therefore, for \$s\$ approaching infinite values (highpass gain) we have \$ H(s) = A_\infty \$.

Comparing both forms of \$H(s)\$ we arrive at the given expressions for \$\omega_p\$, \$Q_p\$, and \$A_\infty=v\$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have an issue with R3 = R4, since this is the unity gain version without utilizing the butter worth coefficients. Is this still considered a Butterworth response?

Comment: For a Butterworth response, you have nothing to do than to set Qp=0.7071. The pole frequency, in this case, is identical to the -3dB frequency.

Comment: Please note that for R3=R4 you have v=2 (and NOT the unity gain version). More than that, it is clear that there are many possible solutions for the resistor resp. capacitor niveaus because the Qp value requires resitor and capacitor ratios only (kr resp. kc).

Comment: You do not need the Butterworth coefficients, because the given eqquation contains the pole frequency as well the pole-Q values.

Comment: Hmm, must have gotten confused since the book I am following listed above, is using these coefficients and online searches show that indeed many times they are used.

Comment: For Butterworth we have wp=wc (3 dB) - that means: b1=1. More than that, the pole Q Qp=0.7071 contains the value of a1 because Qp=1/a1. That means: The equations contain, of course, the coefficients - however, in another form, which is more convenient.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference from where you got the TF listed above, since I may have been following the wrong one... I would also appreciate if you could explain the abbreviations you used in the question, (Example wp is pole frequency) since I am not familiar with the abbreviated terms. Not sure what wc is. I will accept your answer shortly! Thanks

Comment: OK - I will edit my detailed answer.

Comment: The frequency wc is the 3dB-corner frequency which is related to the pole frequecy wp by the factor b1: b1=wc/wp. And for the Butterworth response we have b1=1 (as mentioned before).

Comment: The book sayes "We see that the gain and damping of the filter are linked together. Indeed, for a certain damping factor, only one specific gain will work properly: A=3−α" for a butterworth filter α=sqrt(2) ???

Comment: Vinzent- you comment applies to the "equal-componenet" case only!! Of course, we can use the gain-of-two version for realizing all damping values.

Comment: Okay sure might only apply to the "equal-componenet"-case but that was the one he had used. Besides the book only talkes about that and the "unit-gain"-version. But you are probably right that you can get gain of 2 with a different configuration

Comment: It is simple: The given equations proove that it is possible, indeed.

Comment: By the way i'm trying to work backwards from your quadratic equation to the polynomial=0 with kr with b=-1, a=Qp^2 but because you put +/- inside the sqrt it's imposible for me to know if you had c=2 or c=-2?. I'm having a hard time getting the sqrt(kr)/(2-kr) into polynomial form so i can find a,b and c.

Comment: @Vinzent - But my question to you is: Why are you interested in the coefficients a, b, c ? You do not need them when using wp and Qp. It is a simple task to select suitable parts values based on the formulas mentioned by me. Again: Both pole data wp and Qp contain indirectly the coefficients a, b and c. Note that there are two different ways to specify filter data in tables:  Either using the values a, b, c or using wp and Qp. The latter method is considered in most of the text books because wp and Qp can be measured very easily (and a,b,c cannot).

Comment: Okay I see, yes I understand that, the only reason I was interested in the coefficients you used for the quadratic was because I was working my way through your math to validate it and see what you did, and wanted to see how you got the solution for the quadratic from Qp=sqrt(kr)/(2-kr)..

Comment: ...more complex than needed? When you want to design a 2nd-order filter you have at first to select a suitable circuit. OK - was done by you. And then, you need specific formulas for the parts elements which allow realization of the desired values for wp and Qp. That`s all - and that´s what we have done. Less activities are not possible to arrive at a circuit with parts values.